# Getting messy and numbers are overlapping each others in several using plotxx

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph, matlab-figure

[image]I am plotting several plot by using plotxx, but I do not know why the x and y axis are getting messy and numbers are overlapping each others.

```
[ax,h1,h2] = plotxx(n00,I1,noo,I1);
hold on
plotxx(n0,I2,no,I2);
hold on
plotxx(n0,I3,no,I3);
hold on
plotxx(n0,I4,no,I4);
hold on
plotxx(n0,I5,no,I5);
```

Comment: Show us a screenshot?

Comment: Try same coordinate ranges for all plots n00=n0, noo=no. Also, you can try to write them in one row plotxx(n0,I1,no,I1,n0,I2,no,I2,n0,I3,no,I3);